# What PSU form-factor do I need?

Tags: hardware, power-supply-unit

So I finally got my [Fantec SRC-2080x07](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00HFGJRR4/) 2U server chassis replacement.

Only to find out that the [Be Quiet TFX Power 2 300W Gold](https://www.bequiet.com/en/powersupply/496) PSU that I ordered, is too small to fit.

Here's a picture of the PSU in the server case:

[image]

I thought a TFX form factor would fit because it looked like it had the same 3 mounting holes, but apparently not.

What form factor PSU does this chassis need? or is there maybe a bracket that I can use to still use this PSU? (it's upside down because the fan would be at the bottom otherwise)

Comment: Perhaps [one](http://www.fantec.de/produkte/serverprodukte/netzteile/produkt/details/artikel/2506_sure_star_tc_2u50es/) like the manufacturer sells with the chassis?

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything about the form factor of the PSU. I'd like to buy my PSU from a reputable brand.

Comment: It's a 2U form factor, like the specs say. You can find these anywhere in Europe or the USA.

Comment: But what am I looking for? ATX, TFX, something else entirely?

Comment: No, you are looking for 2U. e.g. search amazon.de for [2U Netzteil](https://www.amazon.de/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&url=search-alias%3Dcomputers&field-keywords=2u+Netzteil&rh=n%3A340843031%2Ck%3A2u+Netzteil&ajr=2) and you will get the correct form factor.

Comment: Okay, now that makes more sense. I only knew 2U from the height of the chassis, I've never heard it being used for PSU's before. Thanks.

Comment: same issue now my rack look like ghetto they got Fantec NT-2U40E but nobody say what for factory it is

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is this adapter you can print it

https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4317040

Bought FSP550-802U and it similar issue its somehow fit on front but not on back and only 2 screw was attached (2 screws front)

**it shoudl have 3 screws on front (i will try it)**

Answer (score 0):

That case uses an ATX/EPS PSU, see https://www.fantec.de/en/products/server-products/19-inch-server-storage-cases/produkt/details/artikel/1670_fantec_src_2080x07/